# Why MongoDB's python motor client is much slower than pymongo when run with starlette?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, python-asyncio

I have a web application written with python and the async framework Starlette (https://www.starlette.io/), I need to connect to MongoDB, so I installed the async pymongo driver: motor (https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) version 2.1.0

And I have some pseudo code like this:

```
motor_client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(...)
pymongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient(...)

class BlogList(HTTPEndpoint):
    async def get(self, request):
        blog_list = [item async for item in motor_client.blog.find(condition)]
        # blog_list = list(pymongo_client.blog.find(condition))
        data = {
            "request": request,
            "blogs": blog_list,
        }
        return RenderPageResponse("index.html", data)
```

For the `blog_list` line here, I benchmarked it with `wrk -t10 -d10 -c100 http://localhost:8080/blog`:

- If I use the `motor_client` with `await`, the result is around "1500 requests/sec"
- If I change it to `pymongo_client` (the sync mode), the result is around "1900 requests/sec"

Shouldn't the async mode with motor be faster than the sync mode with pymongo? 
I am wondering why the performance is much worse when using motor (async, 1500 req/s) compare to pymongo (sync, 1900 req/s)?

Other info: I run my starlette app with `gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker myblog:app`, and just toggle these 2 lines to do the `wrk` benchmark.

I did the search but cannot find posts talking about this, so I am wondering did I miss something? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You're running your queries serially but with the overhead of checking for suspended tasks/futures/etc when the motor client yields back to the event loop. You should take a look at `asyncio.gather` to allow multiple queries to run at a time.

Comment: @dirn thank you for the feedback, but I am not sure I got what you mean. In this request handler, I only have one query, which is like `cursor = motor_client.blog.find({})` then convert it to list like `await [item async for item in cursor]`. I don't have multi queries in this handler

Comment: Oh you're right. I misread it as iterating over queries.

Comment: Does `await [item asymc for item in ...]` work? It looks like an error.

Comment: @user4815162342 right, it is pseudo code, sorry for the confusion, in my actual code, I put `[item async for item in cursor]` inside a async function, so I need to await it. If just return the list, no need to await it. Anyway, sorry for the pseudo code confusion. But the benchmark part where motor is significantly slower than native pymongo really confused me

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps the problem is due to the fact that the motor is not an asynchronous driver in fact. It just starts the synchronous pymongo in ThreadPoolExecutor, hence the performance drop. Unfortunately, currently there is no asynchronous driver for mongo on python :(

Answer (score 9):

I did some experimentation on this using fastapi
First added 1515 documents to a collection in mongodb
Then defined 3 test cases
Test Case 1
Used **pymongo** to fetch documents from database from **sync** function

```
@app.get("/get_data")
def read_data():
    cursor  = coll.find({})
    li = []
    for rec in cursor:
        li.append(rec)
    length = len(li)
    return {"length": length}
```

Test Case 2
Used **pymongo** to fetch documents from database from **async** function

```
@app.get("/get_data")
async def read_data():
    cursor  = coll.find({})
    li = []
    for rec in cursor:
        li.append(rec)
    length = len(li)
    return {"length": length}
```

Test Case 3
Used **motor** to fetch documents from database from **async** function

```
@app.get("/get_data")
async def read_data():
    cursor  = coll.find({})
    li = []
    async for document in cursor:
        li.append(document)
    return {"length": len(li)}
```

Used uvicorn to run the app with 5 workers
uvicorn test:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --workers 5

Used locust for testing
code:

```
class HelloWorldUser(HttpUser):
    @task
    def hello_world(self):
        self.client.get("/get_data")
```

config: 
Number of total user simulated = 50
Spawn rate(per second) = 10

**Results**

Test Case 1

```
 {
   "Type":["GET"],
   "Name":["/get_data"],
   "Request Count":[1546],
   "Failure Count":[0],
   "Median Response Time":[1300],
   "Average Response Time":["1409.07469337902"],
   "Min Response Time":["213.365600000543"],
   "Max Response Time":["6493.73753599866"],
   "Average Content Size":[15],
   "Requests/s":["32.9464475484361"],
   "Failures/s":[0],
   "50%":[1300],
   "66%":[1500],
   "75%":[1700],
   "80%":[1900],
   "90%":[2300],
   "95%":[2700],
   "98%":[3200],
   "99%":[3600],
   "99.9%":[5200],
   "99.99%":[6500],
   "100%":[6500]
}
```

Test Case 2

```
{
   "Type":["GET"],
   "Name":["/get_data"],
   "Request Count":[1586],
   "Failure Count":[0],
   "Median Response Time":[2000],
   "Average Response Time":["2108.97265052965"],
   "Min Response Time":["261.412365001888"],
   "Max Response Time":["5301.57826199866"],
   "Average Content Size":[15],
   "Requests/s":["22.4672730359705"],
   "Failures/s":[0],
   "50%":[2000],
   "66%":[2400],
   "75%":[2500],
   "80%":[2700],
   "90%":[2900],
   "95%":[3300],
   "98%":[3600],
   "99%":[4100],
   "99.9%":[5100],
   "99.99%":[5300],
   "100%":[5300]
}
```

Test Case 3

```
{
   "Type":["GET"],
   "Name":["/get_data"],
   "Request Count":[1662],
   "Failure Count":[0],
   "Median Response Time":[1200],
   "Average Response Time":["1388.38606281409"],
   "Min Response Time":["116.913538000517"],
   "Max Response Time":["7983.01199100024"],
   "Average Content Size":[15],
   "Requests/s":["33.5720588256683"],
   "Failures/s":[0],
   "50%":[1200],
   "66%":[1500],
   "75%":[1700],
   "80%":[1900],
   "90%":[2300],
   "95%":[2700],
   "98%":[3400],
   "99%":[4100],
   "99.9%":[6800],
   "99.99%":[8000],
   "100%":[8000]
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30592255)

Comment: @mbuechmann Even though it doesn't provide an answer, it **does** clarify that motor client is actually slower

Answer (score 0):

Motor might be slower than PyMongo in terms of speed. Performance depends on the  use case under consideration. When using any of the ODMs in an async environment with multiple DB calls, Motor performs better because it doesn't block the event loop. I would suggest using PyMongo if the application is a single endpoint application with DB calls in a synchronized manner.